# Find and replace duplicates in Array

Tags: php, arrays, replace, find, duplicates

I need to make app with will fill array with some random values, but if in array are duplicates my app not working correctly. So I need to write script code which will find duplicates and replace them with some other values.
Okay so for example i have an array:

```
<?PHP
$charset=array(123,78111,0000,123,900,134,00000,900);

function arrayDupFindAndReplace($array){

// if in array are duplicated values then -> Replace duplicates with some other numbers which ones I'm able to specify.
return $ArrayWithReplacedValues;
}
?>
```

So result shall be the same array with replaced duplicated values.

Comment: You might want to check out [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) before needing to write your own method first; they might be just what you need.

Comment: I check that and it don't pass my needs. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: This question would be more clear if you expressed the replacement string(s) that you would like to use and your exact expected result.  A [mcve] @xZero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just keep track of the words that you've seen so far and replace as you go.

```
// words we've seen so far
$words_so_far = array();
// for each word, check if we've encountered it so far
//    - if not, add it to our list
//    - if yes, replace it
foreach($charset as $k => $word){
    if(in_array($word, $words_so_far)){
        $charset[$k] = $your_replacement_here;
    }
    else {
        $words_so_far[] = $word;
    }
}
```

For a somewhat-optimized solution (for cases where there are not that many duplicates), use array_count_values() [(reference here)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to count the number of times it shows up.

```
// counts the number of words
$word_count = array_count_values($charset);
// words we've seen so far
$words_so_far = array();
// for each word, check if we've encountered it so far
//    - if not, add it to our list
//    - if yes, replace it
foreach($charset as $k => $word){
    if($word_count[$word] > 1 && in_array($word, $words_so_far)){
        $charset[$k] = $your_replacement_here;
    }
    elseif($word_count[$word] > 1){
        $words_so_far[] = $word;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here the example how to generate unique values and replace recurring values in array

```
function get_unique_val($val, $arr) {
    if ( in_array($val, $arr) ) {
        $d = 2; // initial prefix 
        preg_match("~_([\d])$~", $val, $matches); // check if value has prefix
        $d = $matches ? (int)$matches[1]+1 : $d;  // increment prefix if exists

        preg_match("~(.*)_[\d]$~", $val, $matches);

        $newval = (in_array($val, $arr)) ? get_unique_val($matches ? $matches[1].'_'.$d : $val.'_'.$d, $arr) : $val;
        return $newval;
    } else {
        return $val;
    }
}

function unique_arr($arr) {
    $_arr = array();
    foreach ( $arr as $k => $v ) {
        $arr[$k] = get_unique_val($v, $_arr);
        $_arr[$k] = $arr[$k];
    }
    unset($_arr);

    return $arr;
}




$ini_arr = array('dd', 'ss', 'ff', 'nn', 'dd', 'ff', 'vv', 'dd');

$res_arr = unique_arr($ini_arr); //array('dd', 'ss', 'ff', 'nn', 'dd_2', 'ff_2', 'vv', 'dd_3');
```

Full example you can see [here webbystep.ru](http://webbystep.ru/all-posts/15-array-unique-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Use the function
    array_unique()

See more info at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Thans for trying to help me. But it just removes duplicates. I wanna replace duplicates instead of removing it.

Comment: This will potentially reduce the size of the array -- the OP doesn't want this.

Answer (score -1):

```
$uniques = array();
foreach ($charset as $value) 
   $uniques[$value] = true;
$charset = array_flip($uniques);
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to use it? For example where to specify with which values duplicates will be replaced?

Comment: This will potentially reduce the size of the array -- the OP doesn't want this.