# Replace repeating value with zero in PHP string

Tags: php

The following is the code

```
<?php
$id ="202883-202882-202884-0";
$str = implode('-',array_unique(explode('-', $id)));
echo $str;
?>
```

The result is

```
202883-202882-202884-0
```

for `$id ="202883-202882-202882-0";`, result is `202883-202882-0`

I would like to replace the duplicate value with zero, so that the result should be like `202883-202882-0-0`, not just remove it.

and for `$id ="202883-0-0-0";`, result should be `202883-0-0-0`. zero should not be replaced, repeating zeros are allowed.
How can I archive that?

More info:
I want to replace every duplicate numbers. Because this is for a product comparison website. There will be only maximum 4 numbers. each will be either a 6 digit number or single digit zero. all zero means no product was selected. one 6 digit number and 3 zero means, one product selected and 3 blank.

Each 6 digit number will collect data from database, I dont want to allow users to enter same number multiple times (will happen only if the number is add with the URL manually.).

Update: I understand that my question was not clear, may be my English is poor.
Here is more explanation, this function is for a smartphone comparison website.
The URL format is `sitename.com/compare.html?id=202883-202882-202889-202888`.
All three numbers are different smartphones(their database product ID).
I dont want to let users to type in the same product ID like `id=202883-202882-202882-202888`. It will not display two 202882 results in the website, but it will cause some small issues. The URL will be same without change, but the internal PHP code should consider it as `id=202883-202882-202888-0`.
The duplicates should be replaced as zero and added to the end.
There will be only 4 numbers separated by "-".
The following examples might clear the cloud!

if `pid=202883-202882-202889-202888` the result should be `202883-202882-202889-202888`
if `pid=202883-202883-202883-202888` the result should be `202888-0-0-0`
if `pid=202883-202882-202883-202888` the result should be `202883-202882-202888-0`
if `pid=202882-202882-202882-202882` the result should be `202882-0-0-0`

I want to allow only either 6 digit numbers or single digit zero through the string.

if `pid=rgfsdg-fgsdfr4354-202883-0` the result should be `202883-0-0-0`
if `pid=fasdfasd-asdfads-adsfds-dasfad` the result should be `0-0-0-0`
if `pid=4354-45882-445202882-202882` the result should be `202882-0-0-0`

It is too complicated for me create, I know there are bright minds out there who can do it much more efficiently than I can.

Comment: Do you want to replace every duplicate numbers or just consecutive duplicates?

Comment: I also want to hear the response to Pilan's question.  Tim's answer assumes that the duplicates are always consecutive.  If they are not consecutive, Tim's answer will fail you.

Comment: Maybe both of you should stop pointing out the same (possible) edge case multiple times `:-)`

Comment: We wouldn't want researchers to overlook this very realistic possibility in their own project. @TimB  The sample input substrings don't seem to be sorted in any particular way, so I find it very possible to have gaps between duplicate substrings.

Comment: @mickmackusa Actually, my take is that the zeroes are just placeholders indicating the _immediately_ preceding value was the same, _not_ similar values across gaps.  Unded your interpretation, gaps would erase original information and make it impossible to piece together the original input later on.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ah i see, like a compression.

Comment: @TimB did you unhammer this duplicate question?  The answer is already here https://stackoverflow.com/q/13215668/2943403 and in fact the other Tim reposted the same advice.

Comment: @Pilan, Tim Biegeleisen's answer didnt worked for me. I want to replace every duplicate numbers. Because this is for a product comparison website. There will be only maximum 4 numbers. each will be either a 6 digit number or single digit zero. all zero means no product was selected. one 6 digit number and 3 zero means, one product selected and 3 blank.

Comment: @HymaP ...so you don't necessarily need to preserve the locations/positions of the first occuring substring? In other words, you could be equally happy if earlier duplicates were converted to zero and only the last occurring duplicate was preserved? Most important yo me is: WHY is your seemingly array-type data being stored as a hyphen-delimited string? Why do you need the zeroes? I feel like your your whole flow may eed a rethink.

Comment: @mickmackusa If you are referring to my answer,I worked it out from scratch. I should have looked/checked for duplicates.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I believe you.  My meaning was only that the accepted answer from the duplicate was represented in your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find and replace duplicates in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215668/find-and-replace-duplicates-in-array)

Comment: What is the status of the question?

Comment: @mickmackusa There appears to be a possible duplicate, correct?

Comment: I orginally felt this question was a duplicate, then hammered it, then TimBiegel un-hammered it and now I cannot close it.  See my [now-deleted Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400360/2943403).  I also felt that the question was Unclear.  So I asked for clarification.  Then the OP improved the [mcve], which raised more questions.  My answer will not be suitable elsewhere -- it is strictly fit for my current perception of the question.  I'd say that the question is either Unclear or a duplicate. @Funk TBH the duplicate isn't a super great mcve either.

Comment: @mickmackusa Ok. Well the thing is here that, if I go and cast a vote other than the possible duplicate already flagged, it'll get hammered which for the life of me, do not understand. So in a way, I can't cast a vote other than hammering and feel that I cannot cast one without showing that I did that to hammer it, I hope you understand what I mean here.

Comment: I think the question is Unclear (you could vote that way) and is more of an XY problem.  I have voiced my concerns about the data structure in an earlier comment. @Funk

Comment: @mickmackusa I'll cast as "unclear" but I am pretty sure it'll be the hammer that will show. I'll edit this comment either way. Edit: Ok, it did take my unclear vote. But pretty sure it would have been the dupe if I would have voted as "not working". It happened to me before.

Comment: @Hyma you have been online recently.  Are you planning to clarify your question details/requirements so that this page can be progressed to a resolution? Please re-read the comments and edit your question to respond to requested details.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I have added some extra details, sorry for the delay. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @Hyma you did not answer my question about the order of the zeros. Please see how my answer writes zeros earlier in the string.  We are also now learning that the substrings need to be validated as 6-digit substrings as well (that non-numeric values are possible).  You haven't shown us how you are processing the sanitized string of four values -- we can assume that you are exploding on the hyphens, right? And your script is simply disregarding zero values, right? I still need to know more so that I can decide if my answer should be edited or deleted.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a array_unique (preserves key), then fill the gaps with `0`. Sort by key and you are done :)

`+` on arrays will [`unify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) the arrays but prioritizes the one on the left.

Code

```
$input = "0-1-1-3-1-1-3-5-0";
$array = explode('-', $input);
$result = array_unique($array) + array_fill(0, count($array), 0);
ksort($result);

var_dump(implode('-',$result));
```

Code (v2 - suggested by mickmackusa) - shorter and easier to understand

Fill an array of the size of the input array. And replace by leftover values from `array_unique`. No `ksort` needed. `0`s will be replaced at the preserved keys of `array_unique`.

```
$input = "0-1-1-3-1-1-3-5-0";
$array = explode('-', $input);
$result = array_replace(array_fill(0, count($array), 0), array_unique($array));
var_export($result);
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/oCMfY).

Output

```
string(17) "0-1-0-3-0-0-0-5-0"
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/5dCXT).

references

- [ksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) - sort by key
- [array_fill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) - generate an array filled with `0` of a certain length

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do it.

```
$id = "202883-202882-202882-0-234567-2-2-45435";
```

From the String you explode the string into an array based on the delimiter which in this case is '-'/

```
$id_array = explode('-', $id);
```

Then we can loop through the array and for every unique entry we find, we can store it in another array. Thus we are building an array as we search through the array.

```
$id_array_temp = [];
// Loop through the array
foreach ($id_array as $value) {
    if ( in_array($value, $id_array_temp)) {
        // If the entry exists, replace it with a 0
        $id_array_temp[] = 0;
    } else {
        // If the entry does not exist, save the value so we can inspect it on the next loop.
        $id_array_temp[] = $value;
    }
}
```

At the end of this operation we will have an array of unique values with any duplicates replaced with a 0.

To recreate the string, we can use implode...

```
$str = implode('-', $id_array_temp);
echo $str;
```

Refactoring this, using a ternary to replace the If,else...

```
$id_array = explode('-', $id);
$id_array_temp = [];
foreach ($id_array as $value) {
    $id_array_temp[] = in_array($value, $id_array_temp) ? 0 : $value;
}
$str = implode('-', $id_array_temp);
echo $str;
```

Output is

```
202883-202882-0-0-234567-2-0-45435
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329).

The essential actions only need to be:

1. Separate the substrings in the hyphen delimited string.
2. Validate that the characters in each substring are in the correct format AND are unique to the set.
3. Only take meaningful action on qualifying value.

You see, there is no benefit to *replacing/sanitizing* anything when you only really need to *validate* the input data.  Adding zeros to your input just creates more work later.

In short, you should use a direct approach similar to this flow:

```
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $ids = array_unique(explode('-', $_GET['id']));
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        if (ctype_digit($id) && strlen($id) === 6) {
        // or: if (preg_match('~^\d{6}$~', $id)) {
            takeYourNecessaryAction($id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I never got the time to test the answers. I will test all of them today and mark the answer. Please check the additional details added in the question.

Comment: If your application is going to explode on hyphens anyhow, then it doesn't make sense to execute the sanitization with regex.  If your script is only taking meaningful action on qualifying numbers, it doesn't make sense to bother replacing substrings in the input data with zeros.

Comment: if the string detects either a 6 digit number or single digit zero, it will work preoperly. But if it detects anything else, no data will be shows. but some design elements work incorrectly.

Comment: Then it seems, you need to repair the scripts that follow this one.  Again, this is an XY problem.  You have cascading problems to solve.  This generally dictates that you need to refactor parts of your application to be more direct and purposeful.  Writing hacky code to suit hacky code will end up turning your code base into garbage that you yourself won't want to maintain -- not to mention other developers that will see your code.

Comment: Thank you for your time. may be it is an XY problem! I was just trying to avoid a bug by removing unwanted characters from the string. You are suggesting to fix that  bug ? which can be avoidable! This 4 numbers can be managed easily, these 4 product IDs are used in multiple sections of the script. I thought it will be easier to fix just one string rather than multiple areas?

Comment: I don't know what actions are taken after the sanitization, but they should all be designed to iterate a clean array of unique and valid ids and nothing else.  Your application needs to be built on stable data.  There is no benefit in designing your scripts to process meaningless zeros.

Comment: This page appears to be abandoned.  Please take action to progress the status of this page.